# UIScrollWith Clickable text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have scrollview with two textview i want that on clicking any of the textview should go the desired information in the detail view

int j=0;

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowOne.count; i++) {
    if (j==1) {

        j++;


    }


    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];

    Book*book=[rowOne objectAtIndex:i];



    CGRect myframe=CGRectMake(107, 46, 258, 128);       




    UITextView*textView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:myframe];


    book.bookID=bookidone;
    textViewOneDescription=book.fulltext;
    [subView addSubview:textView];
    //[backViewButton addSubview:textView];



    NSString* myid=book.bookID;

    NSLog(myid);


    NSString*text1=book.teaser;

    fulltextone=book.fulltext;

    textView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:16];
    NSString*mytext=book.teaser;
    mytext = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    mytext = [mytext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    mytext = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&aring;" withString:@"å"];
    mytext = [mytext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    mytext = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&oslash;" withString:@"ø"];
    mytext = [mytext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];



    mytext = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&aelig;" withString:@"æ"];
    mytext = [mytext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    mytext = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&AElig;" withString:@"Æ"];
    mytext = [mytext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    mytext = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&Oslash;" withString:@"Ø"];
    mytext = [mytext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    mytext = [mytext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&Aring" withString:@"Å"];
    mytext = [mytext stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];



    textView.text=mytext;



    //testButton.tag=j;

    //[testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 







    UIButton*headingButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    headingButton.frame=CGRectMake(20, 10, 300, 35);
    NSString*headingbuttontitle=book.title;
    //NSString*headingbuttontitle=j;

    headingbuttontitle = [headingbuttontitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    headingbuttontitle = [headingbuttontitle stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    [headingButton setTitle:headingbuttontitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //[headingButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [headingButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


     headingButton.tag=j;


    [headingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   
    headingButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    headingButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20 ];


    UIButton*myImageButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(20, 46, 90, 127);
    NSString*thumb2=book.thumbimgurl;
    thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumb2]]];
    myImageButton.tag=j;
    [myImageButton setBackgroundImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.jpg"];
    [myImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   

    [subView addSubview:myImageButton];




    j++;



    CGRect myframe1=CGRectMake(502, 46, 150, 128);
    Book*book1=[rowOneSecond objectAtIndex:i];
    UITextView*textViewtwo=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:myframe1];
    NSString*mytext1=book1.teaser;
    textViewTwoDescription=book1.fulltext;
    book1.fulltext=fulltexttwo;


    book1.bookID=bookid;

    testButton1.tag=j;
    [testButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&aring;" withString:@"å"];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&oslash;" withString:@"ø"];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];



    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&aelig;" withString:@"æ"];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&AElig;" withString:@"Æ"];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&Oslash;" withString:@"Ø"];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&Aring" withString:@"Å"];
    mytext1 = [mytext1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];






    textViewtwo.text=mytext1;
    textViewtwo.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:16];







    UIButton*headingButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    headingButton1.frame=CGRectMake(408, 10, 300, 37);



    [headingButton1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     NSString*headingbutton1title=book1.title;
     headingbutton1title = [headingbutton1title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
     headingbutton1title = [headingbutton1title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    headingButton1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20 ];

    [headingButton1 setTitle:headingbutton1title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//  [headingButton1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        headingButton1.tag=j; 
    // [headingButton1 setTitle:j forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [headingButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
     headingButton1.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;






    UIButton*myImageButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(408, 46, 90, 127);
    NSString*thumb1=book1.thumbimgurl;
    thumb1 = [thumb1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    thumb1 = [thumb1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumb1]]];
    myImageButton1.tag=j;
    [myImageButton1 setBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.jpg"];
    [myImageButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

    [subView addSubview:myImageButton1];






    [subView addSubview:textViewOneLink];
    [subView addSubview:headingButton];
    [subView addSubview:headingButton1];
    [subView addSubview:textViewtwo];
    //[subView addSubview:textView];        


}
```

Comment: why you need textview there then?

Comment: have u tried with UITextView Delegates ?

Comment: i am making an ipad magazine app in which there is scrolling containing news in textviews and when we click on them it goes in detail view

Comment: you can do it by adding button as subview to your textview

Answer (score 0):

You can not tap on textview. May be one work around is that add UIButton transparent on both the textview and implement IBAction for that.

Hope this tweak helps you.

Comment: i am creating textView in a loop Programmatically and if add UIButton transparent on both textview in IB it gives only last value i am giving code above in the question to make you understand

Comment: You can create UIButton in loop as well and give frame same as textview.frame. Make sure you add it to Subview after you add textview so it stay top of textView.

Comment: means if i have UITextView textView

Comment: Did button added on top of textview at all ? Did you try to give background to UIbutton so you can get idea whether button added or not and tap or not.

Comment: I am glad this work for you. Can you mark it answer so other user can take advice from this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can code in this

```
 -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
   {

//do something 

 }
```

Comment: this is for those which we create in IB and connect them through outlet

Comment: i have also posted code in the same question above plz tell me solution

Comment: can you give me email i show you image what i want and i make you clear understandable

Comment: try by adding a button as subview and set target that will push detail view

Comment: CGRect myframe=CGRectMake(107, 46, 258, 128);  
  
  
  
  
  UITextView*textView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:myframe];
  
   
  book.bookID=bookidone;
  textViewOneDescription=book.fulltext;
  [subView addSubview:textView];
  //[backViewButton addSubview:textView];
  
  
  UIButton*teaserButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  
   teaserButton.frame=CGRectMake(107, 46, 258, 128);  

  teaserButton.tag=j;
  
  [teaserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

  [textView addSubview:teaserButton];

Comment: i have added button as a subview to textview but its not working

Comment: CGRect myframe=CGRectMake(107, 46, 258, 128); 
UITextView*textView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:myframe]; 
book.bookID=bookidone; 
textViewOneDescription=book.fulltext;

 //[backViewButton addSubview:textView]; 
UIButton*teaserButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
teaserButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 258, 128); 
teaserButton.tag=j; [teaserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[textView addSubview:teaserButton];
 [subView addSubview:textView];

Comment: @Ali don't forget to accept answers that are appropriate - it's what keeps this site going!